# Why isn't NullPointerException thrown in the console?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, nullpointerexception

I'm building my web application with Spring MVC 3.2 and Spring Security 3.1. 
For authentication, I implement `UserDetailsService` and use `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.
Everything works fine!

However I have a problem with `userDetailsServiceImpl` bean:
when `dbUser` is `null`, `NullPointerException` (at line `dbUser.getUsername()`) is not thrown into the console.

```
package net.dntuan.training.mvc.security.authentication;

import java.util.*;

import net.dntuan.training.mvc.dao.UserDao;
import net.dntuan.training.mvc.security.Role;

import org.slf4j.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.*;

@Service("userDetailsServiceImpl")
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        net.dntuan.training.mvc.domain.User dbUser = this.userDao.getUserByUsername(username);
        logger.debug("dbUser is null? " + (dbUser == null));
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        roles.add(Role.USER);

        User user = new User(dbUser.getUsername(), dbUser.getPassword(), dbUser.getEnable(), true, true, true, roles);
        logger.debug("does not reach here");
        return user;
    }

}
```

console shows as below

```
[DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Creating new transaction with name [net.dntuan.training.mvc.security.authentication.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; '' (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:366)
[DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction (HibernateTransactionManager.java:416)
[DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] (HibernateTransactionManager.java:426)
[DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@2826e5d8] (HibernateTransactionManager.java:487)
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_1_0_, this_.enable as enable2_1_0_, this_.fullname as fullname3_1_0_, this_.password as password4_1_0_, this_.username as username5_1_0_ from public.user this_ where this_.username=?
[DEBUG] [net.dntuan.training.mvc.security.authentication.UserDetailsServiceImpl] - dbUser is null? true (UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:27)
[TRACE] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:936)
[DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Initiating transaction rollback (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:844)
[DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] (HibernateTransactionManager.java:570)
[TRACE] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:965)
[DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction (HibernateTransactionManager.java:632)
```

After debugging with Eclipse, I think it seems like Spring is catching the exception by default.
I'm new to Spring so my questions are: Why does Spring catch it by default? And how does Spring do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you don't see it explicitely mentioned, it doesn't mean that no NPE is thrown. It is most probably thrown which causes the database transaction to roll back as the log messages clearly show that.

**UPDATE:**
Spring's transaction management infrastructure catches exceptions (any `Throwable` in fact) [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.java#L264), and it does so in order to be able to implement the behavior described by the transaction configuration (= the attributes of the `@Transactional` annotation on your method). By default, any `RuntimeException` triggers rollback (see [docs on `@Transactional` settings](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings)), as these are considered unrecoverable error conditions. You'll be able to see the `NullPointerException` thrown from your method mentioned in the logs if you enable *trace* level logging on the `org.springframework.transaction` package.

Comment: I know it's thrown but my question is no NPE is thrown **in console**

Comment: Why do you expect it to appear in the console? There is no universal rule about NPEs having to show up on standard error or smth like that. If your method or some other code higher up on the call stack catches that exception and makes explicit istructions to log/print it, then it will appear, otherwise it won't. Chances are that Spring would report it when debug/trace level logging is enabled on the appropriate packages.

Comment: Thank Zagyi, but I'm new to Spring so I want to know Why does Spring catch the exception? Also could you tell me how does Spring catch it? Thank much again!